# Extra space added after my script

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I just started using AutoHotKey and I wrote the simple script

```
::o::email address
```

however, to enact this text change i press space and it inputs a space after the address. This causes the system to reject my email. It would be great if you could help me with a script that would be a simple 1 or 2 key stroke solution to have the email address input without a trailing space. It would be great if it would `tab` to the next field as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put here any code writing by you and showing us what you try?

Answer (score 1):

What you use is a single character hotstring (most people would use a hotkey, but this works as well.

Normally a hotstring is "finished" by some pre-defined keys like {Enter} or {Space}, but you can define these "end" characters yourself.

One way to no longer need the end characters is to use a few control signs in the hotstring.

```
::o::email address`t ; Your original, requires e.g. {Enter} or {Space}
:*:o::email address`t ; Does NOT require and end character. EVERYWHERE when I write an isolated "o", I get "email address"
:*?:o::email address`t ; Now the "oo" is not even isolate, but can be in a word like "more" becomes "memail addressre"
```

The way I do this is:

```
:*:o\::email address`t ; The "\" is next to my {Enter} key and when I type the combo "o\" I receive "email address"
```

More info on hotstrings can be found here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm
Success